# Can I set locale/language on iPad keyboard in a web app/UiWebView?

Tags: ipad, localization, uiwebview, webkit

I have a UIWebView where user can input stuff by a native keyboard. Is it possible to set locale, so that buttons like Next, Prev and Done is in local language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these are controlled by Safari, which gets the localization from the system.